# Save pandas output into new file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'd like to save the output I get from this piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("inputfile.csv",sep=";",decimal=",", nrows=100)
print (df)
```

to a new file that then only includes the 100 rows from the input-file?

I tried something with 'w', but that didn't really work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the [pandas.Dataframe.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function:

```
 df.to_csv("outputfile.csv", sep=";", decimal=",")
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But in the outputfile, there's suddenly only one column (but still the intended 100 rows), while in the inputfile there are 11 columns. I'd like for the outputfile to have the format 11 x 100.

Comment: You will also need to add the separator and decimal options in the to_csv() function that I just added to the result.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` can also write to `*.csv` files:

```
# Write to file with same separator/decimal setting as in your input file
df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')
```